# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_app.default.firestore')

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

`Hi all, i just started learning react native and while working on this project with firebase firestore, i encountered this issue. I am trying to push some data into the database. I am using Firebase version ^9.14.0

```
firebase.js

import firebase from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";
import "firebase/compat/firestore";


const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: "",
};

// const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// export const auth = getAuth(app);

let app;

if (firebase.apps.length === 0) {
  app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
} else {
  app = firebase.app();
}

const db = app.firestore();
const auth = firebase.auth();

export { db, auth };



Cart.js 

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity, Modal } from "react-native";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import OrderCheckoutList from "./OrderCheckoutList";
import firebase from "firebase/app";

const addOrderToFirebase = () => {
 const db = firebase.firestore();
 db.collection("orders").add({
  items: items,
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  });
   //setModalVisible(false);
};
```

I am not sure if this is related to the firebase v9 or v8, or is it something that i am missing in the source code.`

Comment: it seems like you're probably following some instructions for creating this, can you link them?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jmvbhuJXFow Here's the video i've been following @4:58:00 for the firebase firestore.